# Can I make an ActionBar like this?

Tags: android-layout, android-actionbar, android

bottom border is a nine patch image. is it? or could be?
top border is same like the Android Gmail app refresh (Jelly Bean) but static not animated.

Can anybody help me? I am using API greater than 14.

[image: Proposed ActionBar Design]

Comment: Ok, I'm not answering at all but this is my opinion on this subject. This kind of ActionBar will increase user frustration. It looks like the thing on left opens some kind of menu, which could be drawer or something like a dropdown, can't tell. And there is an icon like thing at the middle. You should know this Android is not iOS. Android apps doesnt have things on the middle of the ActionBar. Don't trade clear interaction for beauty.

Comment: You can have an icon at the middle, @interlude, with a custom actionbar. However, you have definetly right: this is not iOS and Android have a certain design, his own design. Your actionbar, Nodxpert, is really confused.. Keep the guidelines defined by Google on the [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html), this may avoid confusion and (maybe) bad rating.

Comment: @Fllo yes, you definitely can have an icon. You can have an ActionBar horizontally on side, but you shouldn't. That was my point =)

Comment: Interlude convinced me, as a developer and the open source nature of android, this can be done but eventually after the hard work, if that results in a confusion for android user then its better not to touch it. I might try to make it more android-istic action bar. At least I will try to show interlude points to others as not to follow this actionbar design.